# How to print the original stdout format of command by using spawn?

Tags: node.js, bash, shell

I am using the `spawn` to execute `code-push`, which sending an uploading progress to the terminal and with multiple colorful stdout messages.

```js
const codePushProcess = spawn('code-push', [
  'release-react',
  `rrs-${platform}`,
  platform,
  `--deploymentName=${deploymentName}`,
  `--description=${desc}`,
  `--targetBinaryVersion=${version}`,
  '-m'
])
codePushProcess.stdout.on('data', chunk => {
  console.log(chunk.toString('utf8'))
})

codePushProcess.stderr.on('data', data => {
  console.error(`stderr: ${data}`)
})

codePushProcess.on('close', code => {
  if (code === 0) {
    console.log('CodePush Success!')
  } else {
    console.log(`CodePush process exited with code ${code}`)
  }
})
```

Here is a comparison:

[image: Comparison]

When I am using `console.log`, chunks in the terminal are all white without original format, and missing the dynamic progress.

So how to sending the original format to the terminal?

Comment: Try passing the `{stdio: 'inherit'}` option as third argument (and remove the stdout/ stderr event handlers). https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Felix Kling mentioned, passing an option `{ stdio: 'inherit' }` as third argument for `spawn` method will sending the stdio to parent process.

```js
spawn(cmd, [], { stdio: 'inherit' })
```

> 'inherit': Pass through the corresponding stdio stream to/from the parent process. In the first three positions, this is equivalent to process.stdin, process.stdout, and process.stderr, respectively. In any other position, equivalent to 'ignore'.